# How to Apply if else conditioning with HTML2FO tag in RTF Template BI Publisher

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, rtf, bi-publisher, oraclereports, oracle-xml-publisher

My Requirement is to display any particular text eg: 'XYZ' based on the RTF Field UE_GEN_DETAILEDDESCRTF, when UE_GEN_DETAILEDDESCRTF is not null its should display 'XYZ'.
here
UE_GEN_DETAILEDDESCRTF return some HTML values, to get the actual value i used this tag. this works fine.
[image]

However my requirement is to use the html2fo tag with condition.
Below are the options tried but no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Option 1.

```xml
<?xdofx:if element_condition then result1 else result2 end if?>
       <?xdofx:if SOME_FIELD_ELEMENT=100 then 'something' else 'something else' end if?>
```

Option 2.

```xml
<?xdoxslt:ifelse(condition,true,false)?>
      <?xdoxslt:ifelse(SOME_FIELD_ELEMENT=21,'something',’something else’)?>
```